# LINQ how to generate csv file section

Tags: vb.net, linq

I got the problem generating csv file based on the section. I currently using LinqToCsv dll to generate the file. How do I generate the file by section. Please help. Thanks.

Currenly I have 3 section

```
Header Section
Detail Section 
Footer Section
```

Here my codes.

```
TTMSEntities DB = new TTMSEntities();

CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription();
outputFileDescription.NoSeparatorChar = false;
outputFileDescription.FirstLineHasColumnNames = true;
outputFileDescription.FileCultureName = "en-US";

List<HeaderRec> list1 = new List<HeaderRec>();
HeaderRec header = new HeaderRec();

header.RecordType = "";
header.RetailerID = "";
header.FileDate = "";
header.FileSequence = "";
header.LastTransRef = "";
list1.Add(header);

var Data = (from p in DB.TT_TNG_KFC_TRANSACTION_UPLOAD
            select new DetailRec
            {
                RecordType = "D",
                TransIDType  ="AA"
            });

List<FooterRec> list2 = new List<FooterRec>();
FooterRec footer = new FooterRec();

footer.RecordType = "T";
footer.TotalAmount = "100";
list2.Add(footer);

CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();

cc.Write(Data, "TestData.csv", outputFileDescription);
```

How to I concat the List ?

Comment: Please be more specific. Show us your code. Point us to where it is failing and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Can try using using a third "List<object>" to add items from both of the lists..
Or change the List1 to the type "List<object>" and use add HeaderRec and FooterRec to it